# Why only QString are (usually) passed as const?

Tags: c++, qt5

One [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-books-initdb-h.html) among many other:

```
void addBook(QSqlQuery &q, const QString &title, int year, const QVariant &authorId,
             const QVariant &genreId, int rating)
{
    q.addBindValue(title);
    q.addBindValue(year);
    q.addBindValue(authorId);
    q.addBindValue(genreId);
    q.addBindValue(rating);
    q.exec();
}
```

Why shouldn't pass also `int year` as `const int &year`?

Comment: you can as well pass as `const int`, but pass a `const int&` is usually meaningless since int is small and cheap to copy.

Comment: Because it doesn't accomplish anything different? References are good for two things: To be able to modify what is being referenced; Or to stop big and expensive objects from being copied. Passing an `int` is not expensive, and the function doesn't need to modify the value (or rather, it's irrelevant in this case). Passing a reference to a `const` is needed either to stop the copying, or to be able to use temporary objects. Copying is still irrelevant, and temporaries (rvalues) can be passed by value.